# How to choose BIOS priority from within Ubuntu?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

My Gigabyte Aorus BIOS doesn't work because of my GPU.  When I disconnect the GPU the BIOS works again.

I'm looking for an option in Ubuntu to choose the boot priorities of the BIOS.

For example, I want to be able to choose what boots first-- a USB stick, or my second SSD where Linux is installed.

Comment: I’m interested in understanding why you want to do this? Why not - from directly within the bios - set it up the way you want? It’s something that typically doesn’t need changing very often - why do you need to do it via Ubuntu? My computers are always set to boot from usb first - but as there’s no USB connected during boot, it goes to the ssd straightaway.

Comment: The BIOS Basic Input Output System is hardware that runs before ANY OS. This is not something you can change with in an OS.

Answer (score 0):

Restart/power on the PC and hold the shift key right away to get the Ubuntu Grub bootloader, you should see a UEFI setting at the bottom of the list to go into the BIOS/UEFI menu.

Answer (score 0):

If it is UEFI, you can use `efibootmgr` :

From [`man 8 efibootmgr`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/efibootmgr.8.html) :

> ### DESCRIPTION
>
> efibootmgr is a  userspace  application  used  to  [...] **change the boot order**

You can then use

```sh
[root@localhost ~]# efibootmgr
```

To list all entries, for ex :

```
BootCurrent: 0004
BootNext: 0003
BootOrder: 0004,0000,0001,0002,0003
Timeout: 30 seconds
Boot0000* Diskette Drive(device:0)
Boot0001* CD-ROM Drive(device:FF)
Boot0002* Hard Drive(Device:80)/HD(Part1,Sig00112233)
Boot0003* PXE Boot: MAC(00D0B7C15D91)
Boot0004* Linux
```

Then, lookup the entry you need and issue the bootloader change command, let's say you want PXE first and then Linux :

```sh
[root@localhost ~]# efibootmgr -o  3,4
```

Comment: OP never said it was EFI he said it was BIOS.

Comment: @David people (including me) are still calling it BIOS through habit. Unless the machine is really old, it will have UEFI.

Comment: I have 6 machines none of which have EFI guess they are all really old.

Answer (score 0):

The `efibootmgr` tool allows you to set the `BootOrder` if you want to do this permanently, and the `BootNext` setting that overrides the `BootOrder` once.

You can also add and remove boot menu entries there. Any item you want to boot will still need to follow the Secure Boot policy configured in the BIOS.

Comment: OP never said it was EFI he said it was BIOS.

Comment: @David The tag is [tag:uefi] so it is